# Website home for Hubot hosted on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, web, hubot, slack

I currently have a Hubot hosted on a free Heroku account. I'd like to have a website that would work as an endpoint to reach the Hubot from outside the chatting application that the bot is on.

Is there any way to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hubot has a built-in HTTP listener for this : https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/#http-listener

If you use Heroku, you can then send HTTP requests directly to your Heroku Domain `your_app.herokuapp.com/hubot`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look inside your Hubot `src/scripts` folder at the `httpd.coffee` script - it has some HTTP example endpoints already set up, and is pretty easy to follow.